# Is a toggle side affect or propagation side affect, Restful?

Tags: rest

We have a case where as it stands our API looks like

`api/workOptions/{workOptionsId}/items/{workOptionId}`

There exists business logic that only one workOptionId can have a status of "preferred."

Rather than forcing the client to submit an entire resource document containing all sub elements pertaining to individual `workOption`s we want to create a separate resource to handle POSTs or PUTs of individual `workOption`s, e.g.

`api/workOption/{workOptionId}`

The issue is whether it acceptable from a RESTful perspective to toggle "off" the "preferred" status of other `workOption`s in the event that someone POSTs or PUTs to the latter individual workOption endpoint a `workOption` document having a status of "preferred." Thoughts?

We're also faced with creating a "proxy" resource on another resource, i.e. `departments` e.g.

`api/departments/{departmentId}/workOption/{workOptionId}`

Naturally this would imply that posts to the `departments/.../workOption` api would cause a further api call to the `workOptions` api to do the actual update. Are "proxy" sub resources acceptable RESTful practice? I assume it is, i.e. the backend should be an implementation detail and not the concern of the API. However, I'm not completely positive on this.

Comment: `Are "proxy" sub resources acceptable RESTful practice?` -- No, but it doesn't matter.  Your post clearly demonstrates that strictly conforming to REST constraints is not in your best interest.  Just use a POST for what you described.

Comment: it's a proxy but only from the backend perspective. The client doesn't know that it's not an actual subresource. Are you saying REST should reflect what's actually in the database?

Comment: REST actually has a very specific use case, which Roy Fielding describes in his dissertation.  When most people say that they want a REST interface, what they really want is a JSON interface.  REST describes architectural constraints that most companies don't really need.

Comment: Do you have an alternate "paradigm" I can subscribe to? Should this fall under the various guidances found with reference to "microservices" APIs or some other paradigm? Or is this literally just "do what you want, it's your API"?

Comment: I would say its more along the lines of "do what you need," not "do what you want."  And it's clear that strictly conforming to REST constraints is not going to get you there, given your specific requirements.  POST is meant to be a safety valve for those things where you're not going to be able to abide by the constraints.

Comment: So just use a POST for this specific use case.  You can always make the remainder of your API REST compliant, if you wish.  But don't do it just for the sake of REST compliance; do it because it  serves your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is whether it acceptable from a RESTful perspective to toggle "off" the "preferred" status of other workOptions in the event that someone POSTs or PUTs to the latter individual workOption endpoint a workOption document having a status of "preferred." Thoughts?

TL;DR: yes it is fine.  and it is also one of the sources of trade offs that affect your resource design.

The shared understanding of HTTP messages, defined by the HTTP specifications, describes the *semantics* of the different messages.  In other words, we all agree what the messages mean.  But server implementations have a lot of freedom.  Here's Fielding explaining this idea in [2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html):

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property

The semantics of unsafe messages (which include PATCH, POST, PUT) designate that the target resource is what we are expecting to change, but side effects on other resources are not restricted.  For instance, we have this clarification in the definition of [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> A PUT request applied to the target resource can have side effects on other resources....  A successful PUT request on "the current version" URI might therefore create a new version resource in addition to changing the state of the target resource, and might also cause links to be added between the related resources.

So `PUT /a0fe48fc-b341-4493-8ca1-0c2e3152bd26` would change the representation of `/a0fe48fc-b341-4493-8ca1-0c2e3152bd26`, but at the server's discretion it might also change the representations of `/19171bfe-072f-4bfd-8c21-ef2b379c45f1` and `/84535265-b337-46dc-aec4-2304d60b5202`.

Where this gets tricky: [cache](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) is an important REST architectural constraint; we have a shared collection of [semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) to ensure that all general purpose components understand caching the same way.

This includes rules for [cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4); general purpose components will know that a non-error response to `PUT /a0fe48fc-b341-4493-8ca1-0c2e3152bd26` means that previously cached representations of `/a0fe48fc-b341-4493-8ca1-0c2e3152bd26` should be invalidated.

BUT: if the server also changed `/19171bfe-072f-4bfd-8c21-ef2b379c45f1` and `/84535265-b337-46dc-aec4-2304d60b5202`, we *don't* have a way to signal to general purpose components that those representations should *also* be invalidated.

In other words, from the server's perspective three resources changed right away.  From the client's perspective (and the perspective of general purpose components), one resource changed right away, and the other two resources will change *eventually*.

If that's fine, then it is fine and you don't have to worry about it.

But if it isn't fine, then you need to consider whether a different resource design would be more suitable - so that the client is extracting the three different pieces of information it needs from one consistent resource, rather than distributing that knowledge over three resources.

(There are other choices - you could decide that the resource design is right, and that the problem is that you don't want these resources cached.  You're in a distributed information system, it's trade offs all the way down.)

> What about the notion of abstracting multiple APIs behind a virtual API defining a resource that is constructed of other resources?

The implementation details are just that, the client doesn't need to know that the system is so complicated because from the outside it still just looks like a web site.

A common example is something like a storefront: https://www.amazon.com/

The information that makes up that page is coming from all over the place.  Some of it local to the page, some of it linked, some fetched by code-on-demand.  The ones that change frequently probably come from the server itself, those that change more slowly from some CDN, and so on.

But all of those pieces are just documents - we can GET/PUT/POST any of them, and they all understand those HTTP methods in exactly the same way.

BUT (in deliberately capital letters) as far as a general purpose component is concerned, different resources are independent - each resource has its own set of representations, and its own caching rules for those representations, and the fundamental language of unsafe requests *targets one resource at a time*.

Which means that the representations of different resources, as seen by the client, may not be synchronized with each other.  If unsynchronized information is a liability, then you need to account for that in your resource design.

Comment: Right. What about the notion of abstracting multiple APIs behind a virtual API defining a resource that is constructed of other resources? Does that still fall under the RESTful style?

Comment: See response at bottom of revised answer.

Comment: Ok, I take you are saying it isn't RESTful on account of lacking assurance of the semantics of a caching guarantee which is(?) integral to the RESTful architectural style?

Comment: No, closer to say that it _is_ RESTful, but you better be sure you understand the implications of that.

Answer (score 0):

It’s important that a request should be idempotent (making the same request once or twice or 100 times has the same effect). In your case, if setting A to “preferred” changes everything else to “not preferred”, then repeating this 100 times makes no difference.